# PHP file not converting to PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have been trying to generate an invoice using mPDF. I have a layout page called "invoice-layout.php" which communicates with the database to get the details of the customer. I want this page to be converted to pdf. I am using the following code for conversion, but only a blank pdf page shows up after a minute or two.

mpdf code:

```
<?php
    include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
    ob_start();
    include 'invoice-layout.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $mpdf = new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',20,15,48,25,10,10); 
    $mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
    $mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output(); 
    exit;
?>
```

and here is the code of my php layout page:

```
<?php
    include("db_connect.php");
    session_start();
    $qry=$conn -> query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=88");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['client_id'];
    $customer=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id='$user_id'");
    $client=$customer->fetch_array();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        //some scripts and design styles
</head>
<body>
// tables here containing variables having values from the database.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo $content;` and see if it's the value you want.

Comment: remove everything but a single line of html see if that works, start with the basics

Comment: @Dagon i tried that, when i directly wite something as text, it gets printed, but when i add even a simple html page.. nothing, just blank pdf page.

Comment: @Matt echo $content is printing the php page as it should, but when I output pdf, its nothing

Answer (score -1):

Try edit your HTML code to more simple. mPDF have sometimes problems with too nested or too complicated html/css/style code.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer